# Top command strange CPU% usage

Tags: linux, top

On my CentOS 6.3 Server, after an OS restart, I see a strange behavior from the **top** command. In the default view of **top** (which is obviously sorted by CPU%) I see the following:

[image: Screen shot of my top output]

1) Many processes are at 100% (or even much much higher) CPU usage despite the fact that the load average is still very low (Please see the screen shot) and the server is almost doing nothing.

2) Although processes should be sorted by CPU%, they seem to be in a semi-random order: Very low usage processes are still at the bottom but the higher percents are at the top with no specific order! (Please see the screen shot)

I have also double checked and made sure that the sorting is based on CPU% (F > k)

This wasn't the case before the server restart, and I am almost sure I haven't installed any special packages.

Any idea what is going wrong here?

### More observations

More examination gives me the feeling that in my case, **top** is showing a *more* detailed info of resource usage by processes than before. I see processes that I know use CPU resources for a very very very short time and they normally never showed up in **top** before (for example, Nginx). But now, I see them constantly showing up on the top of the list. Still have no idea what the problem is...

Comment: The sorting issue might be because it still sorts by dividing the number of CPUs but I'm not sure. You can confirm by pressing 'H' or 'I'

Comment: About 'H': it switches **top** to Thread mode which is not my case (I use non-thread mode). And about 'I', it switches off the Solaris mode which is also not my case. The default **top** setting is with Solaris mode _on_ and is the same as what I have in my other servers (with same spec) which don't have this issue.

Comment: Any update here? I'm seeing the top's CPU usage at 4000% on my 8 core device.

Comment: The solution was as strange as the problem: So normal OS reboots didn't help. But rebooting, going to Raid controller configuration (it did some auto-config/repair/fix stuff itself), making NO configuration change, and then rebooting again solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This output could be perfectly normal based on your question. Percentages are 100% for each core/thread. Which reflects that the process has many threads if it has such a large percentage.

For example if you have 32 cores and a task used half of your CPU time across all cores this would report as 1600%.

Load average is a very different metric. CPU **usage** is not **utilization**. Meaning if you're only using 2% load average but of that time one process was utilizing half of the load then it would be **50%** not 1%.

Comment: Yes. I am aware that even a single process can cause 1600% CPU usage and in your example probably a load average of about 16. The problem is that I see these strange high cpu usages all the time since that restart. The low **load average** is reasonable since _I know_ that at that time there was no load on the server hence, no high CPU usage was expected.